# Read message structure at runtime from advertised topic

Tags: ros, c++, message-generation, xmlrpc, rosmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been looking in the roscore source code with no success. I want to "read" the structure of a given message (by topic name for example). By structure I mean a tree showing the fields a message has and their data types. The format doesn't really matter (XML, JSON etc.).

Is this possible to do in C++? One of my goals would be to dynamically generate a message container at runtime in c++ (maybe eventually a subscriber too).

The only solution I found right know is to run `rosmsg show MSG` and parse its output.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270369/read-message-structure-at-runtime-from-advertised-topic/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2017-09-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No easy core support for this afaik, but I believe [ros_type_introspection](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_type_introspection) can do what you want.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2017-09-07**:
Thanks, that is exactly what I needed.